# Is there a way to get a list of properties in a singleton and process them? (without hardcoded strings)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a singleton class with lots of properties, growing with demand. Yes, it's big, yes it's deliberate. The data contained is used by multiple not really related classes.

So right now the property count is at astounding 25 or more, and I need to reset the values in them at various points. I currently have a reset method that manually addresses each and every property, but it's becoming a pain to do so.

EDIT: The reset method is declared in the singleton class. technically I only have to write them once, the pain is in verifying that I indeed have them all covered whenever I add/remove properties and come back again in a few days to check for bugs and stuff

Is there a way to get a list of properties in a singleton and process them? I looked at KVC but it gets one property at a time with direct string comparison, I'd better off with manually listing them in the reset method

I found class_copyPropertyList, but the [code from apple documentation here:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW1)  causes Xcode to complain about objc_property_t being an undeclared variable.

I've been looking all over with google search, but pretty much everything is talking about setter/getter and the likes

Comment: "complain about objc_property_t being an undeclared variable" Are you importing the runtime header?

Comment: If you are having to work this hard to maintain a singleton that may be a good indicator that another pattern would fit better.  Would it be possible to break information apart so that only some of the properties need to exist in the singleton?

Comment: Perhaps some of those ivars are closely related and should be extracted into a classes. That would reduce the ivar count and create several cohesive classes the singleton maintains, each taking care of it self. Or as "Uncle Bob" might say: "There are classes hiding in all this ivars and associate methods".

Comment: @JoshCaswell 
Why, that could be the reason! I didn't think of importing runtime header because, well, I didn't see them in the link up there

To stephen:
I try my best to avoid it, but there is no real way. The information contained in the singleton is used all the way to up to 6 view controllers ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure if the code still works, but I have toyed with [automatic dependency injection container for Objective-C](https://github.com/zoul/Factory) and written a [`ClassAnalyzer`](https://github.com/zoul/Factory/blob/master/Source/ClassAnalyzer.m) class that does what you need. I think this is the core:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation ClassAnalyzer

+ (NSDictionary*) propertiesOfSingleClass: (Class) classObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned int propCount = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(classObject, &propCount);
    for (int i=0; i<propCount; i++) {
        NSString *name = [NSString
            stringWithCString:property_getName(properties[i])
            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *attributes = [NSString
            stringWithCString:property_getAttributes(properties[i])
            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        [result
            setObject:[TypeSignature signatureWithString:attributes]
            forKey:name];
    }
    free(properties);
    return result;
}
```

Generally speaking, you either have a very special use case for your code or – much rather – have a big WTF in your design. Sorry if you already know that, it had to be said.

Comment: Thanks for your code example, I didn't import objective c runtime header, so that'd be the problem in my part. I have to transfer singular data between about 15 view controllers, some kind of medium needs to be used. Half of the code in this project is courtesy of the previous dev, not much I can do about that so I have to make do